# Passing a const pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

When working with 3D/2D drawing libraries I often find myself passing a pointer to the render window to each of the drawable object classes that handle drawing themselves onto the canvas.

However, every time I do this, I am concerned that by passing a pointer to the render window the objects themselves could change or corrupt the render window itself - which seems unsafe to me.

However, I don't want to make the render window immutable, because by drawing the object onto it I presumably change it's data (This is an assumption, I don't have access to the implementation).

*My question is:* what is the best way of passing a pointer/reference of an object such as a window handle, to another object that needs to call it's members (which may make changes to it's underlying data structures), but without leaving it open to being corrupted by the object it is being passed to.

I feel that my above question terms may be contradictory, if this is the case, please explain why my design pattern is wrong, and a better pattern for this kind of interaction that I could use.

I am not talking about any library in particular, but in my code example below I will reference [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/)

And obviously, I'm using raw pointers for visual clarity in my example, I'd normally use unique_ptr or shared_ptr.

Code Example:

```
namespace sf {

    class RenderWindow;
    class Shape;
}

class DrawableObject;

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow* window = new sf::RenderWindow(x,y,z,bla,bla,bla);

    DrawableObject object = DrawableObject(window);
    object.draw();

    delete window;
}

class DrawableObject {

    public:
    // So here is where my issue exists, by passing a pointer to the window, I could in theory corrupt it and change it's settings from within this class...
    DrawableObject(sf::RenderWindow* _window) 
        :
        windowReference(_window),
        renderShape(sf::Shape(x,y,z,bla,bla,bla))
        {           
        }

    void draw() {

        windowReference->draw(renderShape);
    }

    private:

    sf::RenderWindow* windowReference;
    sf::Shape renderShape;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on the function you're calling; if that function expects a non-const reference/pointer then you have no option but to supply such

Comment: "This is an assumption" don't assume - look at the function signature.  If it's a const function then you can pass around a const reference/pointer.  If it's not const, then you can't

Comment: This is just plain paranoia. If you don't want to corrupt the object, then don't write code that corrupts the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a pointer to something else. For example, pass a pointer to a safe-to-use interface `RenderWindow` derives from (e.g. `IDrawSurface`), or define a safe-to-use [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) you can pass instead:

```
class SafeRenderWindowPtr {

public: /* Methods: */

    SafeRenderWindowPtr(std::shared_ptr<RenderWindow> window) noexcept
        : m_window(std::move(window))
    {}

    void draw(Shape &);

private: /* Fields: */

    std::shared_ptr<RenderWindow> m_window;

}; /* class SafeRenderWindowPtr */

// In some cpp file:
void SafeRenderWindowPtr::draw(Shape & s) { return m_window->draw(stuff); }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a pointer to a const object(e.g. `const sf::RenderWindow* _window`) then you can call only those methods of the `sf::RenderWindow` which are declared as const.
If you want to call non-const methods, there is no (clear) way to store a pointer to a const object.
There is no way to protect yourself against object corruption other than just use it properly.